# Change event listener on

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events

I have some variable `let newBl = someFunction` which subscribing on some data coming, and I have declaring of some listener `newBl.on('data',(data)=>{})`. I can remove this listener like `newBl.off('data')`, but I need redeclare this this listener. Is there are some method for this like `newBl.change()` or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried `newBl.off('data').on('data',(data)=>{})`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki its working, but i want to find some method for using less code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separated function so you could reuse it withour repeating yourself like :

```
newBl.off('data').on('data',(data)=>{
    common_function(data);
});

function common_function(data){
    //Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a little bit more code? Instead of "some" could you be more precise?
Otherwise I would think that I could do:

```
let newBl = someFunciton;

function runMyEvent(newBl){
newBl.on('data',(data)=>{})
}
```

and call runMyEvent whenever I need to run the event.